# How to track Google chrome extension (UA-XXXX) with GA4 ID

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a new Google Chrome extension, that i want to track using the built-in Google analytics tracking. My Chrome extension dashboard has a field for "Google analytics ID", (UA-XXXX) however I can only create new Google Analytics properties using the new Google Analytics 4 (GA4) type, which uses a different Google analytics ID format (G-XXXX)

What do i put into the Google Chrome extension "Google analyics ID" fiekd (UA-XXXXXX) to track it with my GA4 property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant.   If the tracker was designed to work with UA analytics you need a UA-XXXX property id to track data with it.

You need to find one that is designed to work with GA4 and accepts a G-XXXX code.

Comment: or make a UA property and use UA till it's still available, hoping that the capabilities would update and make it possible for using ga4.

Comment: I didn’t realize I could even make a UA style property still. I’ll have to dig into that for now

Comment: As far as i know you can not create UA properties anymore.  UA is shutting down in January,  google wants people moving to GA4.

Answer (score 0):

it is still possible to create 2 properties (for old analytics and for GA4) but 'google analytics tracking ID' for GA4 contains only digits, no UA at all. in the question G-XXXX format is mentioned, this format corresponds to 'measurement ID' not to 'google analytics tracking ID'. and I believe it's not the same at all. so for GA4 there are 2 IDs (both without UA) and it's still not clear which one we have to put in "Google analytics ID"...